# Using a CSS in ScrewTurn Wiki

Tags: css, screwturn

We use ScrewTurn Wiki and I created a Wiki page that contains the CSS information. I used:

<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://wiki.ourcompany.net/tech.CSS-Master.ashx">
</head>

as the link in all the other Wiki pages as the reference for the CSS info, where Tech is the namespace and CSS-Master is the Wiki page containing the CSS info.

This worked fine for a while, then suddenly it just stopped working. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to apply this CSS across your whole wiki?  There's actually a lot you can do with theming.  In the main directory on your webserver, there's a 'Themes' subdirectory, where you can make a new folder for a theme, then you can select a theme in the Administration->Configuration page, as well as when you're editing a namespace (if you want to change the theme for a particular namespace).